# Is using the sniper rifle's "aim" ability as bad as it seems?

Tags: planet-mercenary

Long guns, aka sniper rifles are defined as being good "when you need to kill something from a long distance" (page 139). But Planet Mercenary doesn't worry about range, so that has no mechanical effect. Long guns such as the Blattco 12mm Breaker Bar have the Sniper quality. According to the table on page 153 "When you attack with this weapon as our only action in a round and hit your target, they suffer 1d6 additional damage."

Given that the weapon has a base of 3d6 and each character gets two actions per round, why would I use the Sniper quality? There is no bonus to hit, so I'm trading off a potential 3d6 of damage (from a second shot) for 1d6 of damage. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Sniper quality is not going to be as good as taking a second shot in most cases. The big exception that comes to mind is heavy armor. A reduction of 8 (or with a Goaltender 11-13) is statistically likely to swallow up most of the additional 3d6 of damage from taking a second shot instead of using the Sniper quality. Sniping allows you to make sure that bonus damage punches through on heavily armored targets.

Secondarily, getting bonus damage from sniping also saves you a second attack roll and a potential Mayhem card.